# Show Different Number of Products Per Row

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, category-products

How to show three products in one row of products grid and two products in alternative rows.

It is similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460773/different-number-of-products-per-row-in-magento

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a repeating pattern? Always three products in the first row and two products in following?

Comment: yes its a repeating pattern as you said.

Answer (score 1):

In Your theme's list.phtml, in loop you can give add different class (for e.g. for bootstrap based theme you can use `span4` and `span6`). To add these different classes you can place a `if` condition on counter variable (like if counter%2 equals 0 then some class)

Comment: Could you show an code example?

Answer (score 1):

The Sass/CSS that handles the responsive grids in the Magento RWD theme is pretty complex, as it was designed to allow developers to easily change the number of columns on large screens using XML like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">   
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

In order to accomplish this, you'll need to edit the CSS found in `scss/module/_product-list.scss` product-grid mixin. The Sass in that file is pretty complex, since it was built to handle up to 6 column grids, so you may be better off scrapping it and using it as a template to write your own Sass/CSS.